# Why does ctrl + alt + f2 put Thinkpad into a TTY but when docked it puts it to sleep?

Tags: 14.04, suspend, hibernate, tty

When I hit ctrl + alt + f2 on my Thinkpad I get a tty, great. However, when I hit ctrl + alt+ f2 with an external keyboard (MS Natural if it matters) when I am docked  it puts me to sleep.

What is going on here?

Answer (score 0):

Because some keyboards have primary function of F1-F12 buttons function keys as expected and some have the primary key of F1-F12 buttons set to the secondary functions usually present on laptops (sleep, volume, screen brightness, etc.)

Some keyboards even have Fn-lock key with similar functionality as Caps or Num lock. So with your external keyboard it is obviously that way that Fn the other functionality is primary on function keys. If you have Fn key you should probably press ctrl + alt + Fn + F2 or make the keyboard to use function keys as the primary function of these keys. Then you would put it to sleep with Fn + F2.